# UICollectionView - How to update all cells with change from one cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a `CollectionView` and inside each *cell* of this `collectionView` there is one `textField`.

If all content of the `textfield` is `nil`, when I change content of one `textfield` (for example **cell_1**) all other `textfield`s will auto update content with **value** like the content of `textfield` in **cell_1**.

I have tried with `collectionView.visibleCells` but it does not work properly for my scene.

Is there any way that I can change one cell then update for all cells in `CollectionView`?

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not fully following you, is your problem that all cells get the value of **cell_1**, or is it that you want all cells to update to the value of **cell_1** as soon as you enter something in the `textfield` in **cell_1**?

Comment: @PaulPeelen I want all cells to update to the value of cell_1 as I enter somethings in the textfield in cell_1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Clear new cells:**
Since I am not understanding your question to a 100%, I assume that your problem is that new cells get the value of **cell_1**, which is not something you want.

If that is the case, then there is a function called `prepareForReuse` in `UICollectionViewCell`. 
In your subclass of the `UICollectionViewCell`, implement the following:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    textfield.text = ""
}
```

That should do the trick, given that your `textfield` is called `textfield`.

> Performs any clean up necessary to prepare the view for use again.
>   https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionreusableview/1620141-prepareforreuse

**Update all cells:**
If your question is how to update other cells to get the same content as **cell_1**, then this means that the Collection View subclass needs to know about an update in **cell_1** and then transform that update to the other cells.
One way of doing that is having your `textfield`s delegate set in the Collection View. When the value is changed (`textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString:)`), get all the visible cells and update those `textfields` accordingly. Maybe also save either a reference to the `textfield` in **cell_1**, or a string variable in your Collection View stating the latest entered value so you can update cells as they get rendered.
You **don't** want to use `reloadData()` though, since that will remove the focus from the `textField`, since the `textField` is reloaded.

Solution:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    fileprivate var customString: String?
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

        cell.textField.delegate = self
        cell.textField.text = customString

        return cell
    }

}

extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        customString = string

        for cell in collectionView.visibleCells {
            if let cell = cell as? CustomCell,
                let text = textField.text,
                cell.textField != textField {
                cell.textField.text = text+string
            }
        }

        return true
    }

}
```

The only con in the code above is that it loops through cells that currently are visible. Usually I'd recommend to stay out of looping unless absolutely necessary, but the alternative to the solution above would be to post a notification and having the cells listen to that notification and update its content accordingly. Doing that would not only be overkill, but also something notifications aren't really meant for. Third option would be to hold a weak reference in an array to every textfield, which might not be optimal as well since it creates unnecessary overhead. After all `visibleCells` already is an array of the cells currently visible which each hold a reference to an `UITextField`.

Answer (score 1):

try this -

Step 1 -

Create a variable like and IBOutlet of your collection view  -

```
var xyzString: String?
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView! // IBOutlet of your collection view
```

Step 2 -

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "TagViewCell", for: indexPath) as? TagViewCell // instead of TagViewCell give your custom cell class name
    if self.xyzString != nil {
      cell?.txtField.text = self.xyzString // if you want same value for all cell
     }
    return cell!
}
```

Step 3 -

```
  func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    self.xyzString = textField.text
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Will fail. `cell?.txtField` will be of type `UITextField` which does not conform to `String`. Also, no need for the `if case` since `UITextField.text` is of optional type `String`. Setting `cell?.txtField.text = xyzString` should be sufficient enough since `xyzString` is also optional `String`. Also, `xyzString` will not get updated unless the focus is dropped from the `UITextField`, if I am not misstaken.

Comment: @PaulPeelen -  Thanks for your feedback. :)

Comment: Also, `reloadData()` will remove focus from the `textField`, hence will not be possible to enter more then 1 char at the time. FYI.

Comment: @PremaJanoti Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: @PaulPeelen  You really enthusiastic, thạnk you very much

Comment: Had some time on over. yw